# Set nemo file manager preferences via cli, array data type

Tags: gnome, thunar, gsettings, nemo

I use the following commands to override default settings in `Ubuntu` UI, which works fine:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Yaru-dark'
gsettings set org.nemo.preferences show-home-icon-toolbar true
```

But when I try to change the following setting, it gives me an error. It looks like I have to provide an array of values. I tried to do it, but it didn't work. Which is the appropriate way to set it?

```
gsettings list-recursively |  grep bulk
# org.nemo.preferences bulk-rename-tool @ay []

gsettings set org.nemo.preferences bulk-rename-tool "thunar --bulk-rename"
# unknown keyword:
# thunar --bulk-rename
# ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gvariant text format specifier `@ay` appears to mean an *array of non-null bytes*, aka a [byte string](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/gvariant-text.html#bytestrings)

```
$ gsettings list-recursively |  grep bulk
org.nemo.preferences bulk-rename-tool @ay []
org.gnome.nautilus.preferences bulk-rename-tool @ay []
```

so the syntax is either `"b'thunar --bulk-rename'"` or `'b"thunar --bulk-rename"'` (the two quote styles are equivalent):

```
$ gsettings set org.nemo.preferences bulk-rename-tool 'b"thunar --bulk-rename"'
```

giving

```
$ gsettings list-recursively |  grep bulk
org.nemo.preferences bulk-rename-tool b'thunar --bulk-rename'
org.gnome.nautilus.preferences bulk-rename-tool @ay []
```